# Google OAuth Installed Application Flow: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am trying to follow this guide: [Using OAuth 2.0 for Installed Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#example)

I get past the first part OK where a user can authorize my app to access their Google Drive. I have successfully retrieved the authorization code after the user grants permission.

Unfortunately I get stuck on the second part: I keep hitting a `redirect_uri_mismatch` error when sending the POST request to exchange the authorization code for an access token.

The guidance says I should use "The redirect URI you obtained from the Developers Console". I downloaded the credentials from this link in the developers console:

[image: Google developer console]

Which contained a JSON with the following property:

```
"redirect_uris":["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","http://localhost"]
```

I have tried the request setting `redirect_uri` to each of these options; I have tried with setting it to an empty string; I have also tried with it missing altogether. Nothing works.

Each time I hit the `redirect_uri_mismatch` error.

I have also tried posting to this URL from the downloaded credentials:

```
"token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
```

and also the URL from the guidance page (https://www.googleapis.com//oauth2/v4/token) but each time I hit the same error.

How can I resolve this error and successfully exchange the authorisation code for an access token?

Screenshot example from Fiddler showing one of the many requests I have attempted:

[image: Fiddler screenshot]

Or a raw HTTP Request example:

```
POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Length: 253
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

client_id=175836713882-m783k1ksu2rc6vepq35j4o8hhpk94ndj.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=A---removed-for-security---A&code=4---removed-for-security---E&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=urn%3aietf%3awg%3aoauth%3a2.0%3aoob
```

**N.B. I am aware there are many answered questions on SO about this error with respect to miss-spells of redirect URIs for those following the [Web App Authentication flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) but this specifically relates to the [Installed application flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp). I could find no answered questions relating to this error message on the Installed Application flow**

Comment: Could you post the code you are using for authentication.  If you use http://localhost it will return the code to the localhost webserver.   urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob will return the code in the browser title.

Comment: @DaImTo I think you are referring to the first part to get the authorization code in the first place? That part is working ok for me - this question refers to the second request to exchange that authorisation code for an access token.

Comment: Taking the authentication code and exchanging it also requires a redirect URI.  And remember its a HTTP post.  Could you share some code?  Without seeing your code and being able to recreate the problem myself it will be very hard for myself or anyone else to help you.

Comment: @DaImTo I have not included any code because the question isn't language-dependant. I have, however, updated the question to include the raw http POST request from Fiddler rather than just the screenshot. This sould give enough details for anyone looking to recreate the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occures when the redirect URI set in the authorization request and the redirect URI set in the token request are not the same (it MUST exactly match one of the values listed above).

IMHO, you should first verify the `redirect_uri` parameter in your autorization request. It should be something like:

`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=175836713882-m783k1ksu2rc6vepq35j4o8hhpk94ndj.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn%3aietf%3awg%3aoauth%3a2.0%3aoob`

Comment: I had appended `:auto` to the redirect uri in the authorisation request but not the token request.

Comment: Google also allows the reverse DNS of the client id. In my case the correct redirect_uri was something like "com.googleusercontent.apps.12345667890123-afewijewjfpoiwefjweapiofjewpoifj4:/oauth2redirect"

Comment: The redirect_uri is invalid for google because it does not have ''https://" in the beginning ?